# IISExpress Custom Domains

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

I've been (successfully) running a couple of ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4.6.2, WebForms) websites through Visual Studio 2017 / IISExpress using custom domains. I installed Visual Studio 2019 (Community) the other day, and all of a sudden the custom domains have stopped working on all projects in both Visual Studio 2017 and 2019! The system-tray for IIS Express still continues to show that the binding is accepted:

[image]

However, when attempting to browse to that URL, Chrome gives me a "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error:

[image]

Just to be clear, the steps are taken on each project are as follows:

1. Modify the `applicationhost.config` file in the web project's `.vs` folder to include:

`<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:agentdesktop.local" />`

2. In an elevated command prompt, execute:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://agentdesktop.local:80/ user=everyone`

3. Add to the hosts file:

`127.0.0.1    agentdesktop.local`

I've deleted the `.vs` directory, removed the `urlacl` entry, removed the `IISExpress` directory in the `Documents` folder. Performed all actions outlined above as had been done previously, and still I cannot get it to accept the connection!

If I ping agentdesktop.local then I get a valid response from 127.0.0.1, and the fact it's appearing in the IIS Express system tray, makes me think that something in between is intercepting and blocking.

Does anybody else have any ideas as to how I could get this back working again, or what might have gone wrong!?

Comment: VS2019 uses a different config file, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-solution-file

Comment: Apologies, I was referring to the `applicationhost.config` file generally within the `.vs` directory, it just so happens that, yes, it is in a project-specific directory.

Comment: In case the above comment was unclear, I was deleting the correct (and only) config file within the `.vs` directory. The issue still remains!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some more digging, and found that running

`netsh http show iplisten`

Had a single entry of `::1`. I removed this using:

`netsh http delete iplisten address=::1`

and everything started working again. Not quite sure what happened, but glad I found it.